# Problems with Unitests and VS2012 Update 2 CTP 4

Tags: c#, unit-testing, visual-studio-2012

Since installing the new CTP4 yesterday, it's not possible for me to run Unittests again. When I start them, VS compiles them, and then they stay in "Pending" state and nothing happens. The same happens when I try to Debug them. Is this a known problem or has anyone help?

Comment: Do any of your unit tests work? Where is your mouse cursor when you start a test? What method do you use to start a test?

Comment: No, none of them works... I use the unittests window

Answer (score 2):

After I installed VS update 2 ctp 4 I experienced a similar issue but with the resharper test runner only. Using VS test runner worked.

I complained on twitter and someone from JetBrains sent me here:

http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issueMobile/RSRP-339987

So it is a known issue with and ongoing fix.

No clue if this is your problem as well since you don't specified you are using resharper, but I just wanted to share it. I have no enough reps to comment yet :(

Comment: I use resharper, but I tried also with the Ms-Tool but I will look again!

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue. A workaround is to use the Developer Command Prompt (type it into the Start Menu) and `cd` to your test projects output and run

```
mstest /testcontainer:YourTest.dll
```

It will print all tests then at the end some statistics. You can load the results into VS2012 in your Tests Results window from the output folder for your tests project.